# Optimizing Mobile Layout in AVADA: Maintaining 4 Columns on Desktop and Displaying 2 Columns on Mobile Devices

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress, using the AVADA theme, a site configured with four columns defaults to a single-column layout on mobile devices. Conversely, configuring the site with six columns results in a two-column layout on mobile. The objective is to maintain a four-column configuration while achieving a two-column display on mobile devices.

the product display must be 4 columns desktop and 2 columns mobile. orders are managed by woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using CSS media query,

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .your-column-cls {
  width: 25%; 
  }
  }

  /* Two columns on smaller screens (mobile) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .your-column-cls {
   width: 48%
   }
  }
```

Please replace this class with your exact class which your using for the column "your-column-cls".